# prevent google chrome to download video - Android Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome

I have an application and i am using jwplayer on it. On Android chrome browser, There are an option of download video when any one long press the video. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Can i disable this option through jquery or something else? I have already tried to disable long press using following functions but it still not disable.

```
  function absorbEvent_(event) {
      var e = event || window.event;
      e.preventDefault && e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation && e.stopPropagation();
      e.cancelBubble = true;
      e.returnValue = false;
      return false;
    }

    function preventLongPressMenu(node) {
      node.ontouchstart = absorbEvent_;
      node.ontouchmove = absorbEvent_;
      node.ontouchend = absorbEvent_;
      node.ontouchcancel = absorbEvent_;
    }
```

Any help to disable it?

Comment: I have also same issue. Please someone suggest.

Comment: @YeWin. Disabling context menu work for me. Please see my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have disabled the context menu. Due to this, this menu option not shows up. 
Here is the js code through which i have disabled. Hope this help any one else.

```
window.oncontextmenu = function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
         event.stopPropagation();
         return false;
    };
```

Comment: I already try but no work. Let me know you just pasted this JS code in your JS file?

Comment: @YeWin. i have put it in the footer before the body end tag. fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uvuxqaov/. To verify it, right click menu is working on your site?